# Scanning without taking pictures in BlackBerry OS 6

Tags: blackberry, scanning, autofocus

I'm working on a project that requires me to use the video control. My goal is to turn the camera on and use it to scan some words. I don't want to take pictures out of it. I would need to capture the image automatically when the image is focused instead of having the users taking pictures by pressing the button. What I have in mind right now is there is a state where your camera auto-focuses, if I can somehow catch that state and take the snapshot, then I don't have to ask the user to take a picture. I have no idea how to achieve this. Can anyone shed some light on me please?

If any of you have used something like a barcode scanner like barcode assistant or the canadian tire app, I want something like that.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You'll find this BlackBerry Developer Documentation article useful:
[Take a picture in a BlackBerry device application](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17968/Take_a_picture_in_a_BB_device_app_1228201_11.jsp)